# Maxima indexed variables assigned in evaluation of function

Tags: function, evaluation, maxima

I'd like to use an indexed variable in a function definition (this is a MWE, in the real world I have many `a[i]`, used as coefficients of a polynomial)

```
f(x):=a[0]*x $
```

But when I evaluate this function assigning a value to `a[0]`, the assignment is ignored:

```
ev(f(z),[a[0]=99]);
> a[0]*z
```

In order to get the *desired* result I need to make an additional assignment

```
expr:f(z) $
ev(expr,[a[0]=99]);
> 99*z
```

What's happening here? Is there a way to avoid the additional step?

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: I've investigated this problem some more, and at this point I think that we should accept the observed behavior as being OK. I'm not really happy about it, but it is documented, and changing it will break existing uses of `ev` to effect substitutions for non-atomic expressions. For the record the documentation is: "If 'V' is a non-atomic expression then a substitution rather than a binding is performed." I agree that's very easy to overlook. This bug report has a little more about my thoughts on this issue: https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/3526/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that if you write the function as `f(x) := a0*x` and then `ev(f(z), a0=99)`, you'll get the expected result `99*z`. The different behavior for `f(x) := a[0]*x` is therefore a bug; I'll file a bug report.

In general a more predictable strategy for replacing placeholders with values is to use the `subst` function which substitutes values into an expression. In this case you could write:

```
subst (a[0] = 99, f(z));
```

If you have several values to substitute, you can write:

```
subst ([a[0] = 99, a[1] = 42, a[2] = 2*foo], myexpr);
```

where `myexpr` is an expression containing `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]`.

`subst` is serial (one value at a time) substitution. See also `psubst` which is parallel substitution (all values at once).